# Data is "lastName, FirstName". I need to write it as "FirstName LastName"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, parsing, coalesce

Running sql server 2008 The title says it, but in my select statement I have this

```
COALESCE( ca.AttributeList.value('(/AttributeList/IRName)[1]','varchar(max)')
        ,ca2.AttributeList.value('(/AttributeList/IRName)[1]','varchar(max)'))
      AS IR_Name
```

and it returns `lastName, FirstName`

This becomes a problem when exporting to a csv as it creates two separate columns and what not.

I somehow have to figure out how to have the string be `firstName lastName`, no commas, and putting the firstName first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE('John , Doe', ',', '.'), 1) + ' ' + PARSENAME(REPLACE('John , Doe', ',', '.'), 2)
```

this will switch 'John , Doe' to 'Doe John'. Now, you just need replace the 'John, Doe" with the

```
   COALESCE(ca.AttributeList.value('(/AttributeList/IRName)[1]','varchar(max)'),ca2.AttributeList.value('(/AttributeList/IRName)[1]','varchar(max)')) AS IR_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is by using string functions:

```
select (case when IR_Name like '%,%'
             then (ltrim(rtrim(substring(IR_NAME, charindex(',', IR_NAME)+1, 1000))) + ' ' +
                   ltrim(rtrim(left(IR_Name, charindex(',', IR_NAME) - 1)))
                  )
             else IR_NAME
         end) t
from (select COALESCE( ca.AttributeList.value('(/AttributeList/IRName)[1]','varchar(max)')
                      ,ca2.AttributeList.value('(/AttributeList/IRName)[1]','varchar(max)'))
             AS IR_Name
      . . .
     ) t
```

The trimming functions are to remove extra spaces.

The `parsename` solution is clever.  But, it looks strange since parsename is designed for multipart naming conventions, with up to four parts separated by periods.